# Storm Cluster UI Rest API not behaving as documented

Tags: apache-storm

I've been exploring if the REST API for the Storm UI could be used to extract detailed info about the topology configuration (locations of bolts). http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/STORM-UI-REST-API.html is the source doucmentation. We are running version 1.0.1 of Storm.

This shows the summary of the topology, as expected

```
http://0.0.0.0:9099/api/v1/topology/summary
```

Where "0.0.0.0" is a placeholder for our server.

In the above summary, the topology ID is given as "sdp-acs-cit-why-12500-why-12500-cit-why-cit-service-WHY_TOPOLOGY-1-1500659867".

That is what I would expect. However, this does not work well:

```
http://0.0.0.0:9099/api/v1/topology-workers:sdp-acs-cit-why-12500-why-12500-cit-why-cit-service-WHY_TOPOLOGY-1-1500659867
```

Nor does the route /topology:id with the above ID.

Anyone ever got these to work?

The error message says:
    NotAliveException(msg::sdp-acs-cit-why-12500-why-12500-cit-why-cit-service-WHY_TOPOLOGY-1-1500659867)

That makes me wonder if Storm is misconfigured somehow. Storm operates as expected as far as running the topology goes. It does what we want.

Comment: A pull request was submitted and accepted on this documentation error: https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/2235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like this

```
http://host:port/api/v1/topology/id
```

the `id` is `sdp-acs-cit-why-12500-why-12500-cit-why-cit-service-WHY_TOPOLOGY-1-15006598`67

Answer (score 0):

The colons shown in the documentation are incorrect. Just a slash should be used before the topology ID.

```
.../topology-workers/sdp-acs-...
.../topology/sdp-acs-...
```

Both work.